# Scrollview creates the insets when keyboard appears but doesnt automatically move up to textview

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a scrollview and it creates the insets perfectly with the observers. The problem is that I tap on the textview, keyboard moves up, but then I need to scroll down to get to the textview. How can I fix this to automatically scroll up instead of me scrolling down?

Comment: you can use this pod to handle your issue so you don't need to add observer:-https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

Comment: you can try using constraints.
When keyboard is up, increase constraints and scroll up using offset

Comment: Use Notification Center to get the callbacks when keyboard is hiding and showing and then on those methods calculate height of the keyboard then play with constraints as your use case .